# What is the importance of gulp-contrib-copy package

Tags: gulp

I'm not able to figure it out the importance of `gulp-contrib-copy`

Without `gulp-contrib-copy` package

```
gulp.task('task2', function () {
       gulp.src('dir1/**/*.js')    
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
   });
```

With `gulp-contrib-copy` package

```
gulp.task('task2', function () {
    gulp.src('dir1/**/*.js')
    .pipe(copy())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

End results are same for the code snippets, are there any cases we have to use this package? I haven't found much in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how gulp works. Gulp takes a stream of input from the previous method, and pipes each part of it to the next, not all at once. This is great for low memory usage. You don't have to pass any parameters to `copy()` the code is fine. What matters is what was called before and after copy.

- gulp.src - Add source files
- pipe(copy()) - Reads files and pipes data through
- pipe(gulp.dest('dest')) - Writes the files that were read

How you are doing it now is fine.